# Nodejs jquery reload div part of page ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node.js

I am trying to reload only part of a html page using jquery after a ajax call and everything I've tried gets me 404 not found.  Does the jquery.load not work with node js and if so what is a workaround to get one div to reload without reloading the whole page?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/high",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var highbtn = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(highbtn);
            $('#high').load('/Public/userphotoview.ejs' + ' #high');


        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("error fetching data");
        }
```